# Creating two separate plots on Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I know this question is probably asked frequently but I've been unable to find an answer. I have created a plot by using the following code:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.loglog(a,b, basex = 2, label = 'mergesort')
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel('Time Taken')
matplotlib.pyplot.title('Time vs 2^i')
matplotlib.pyplot.legend()
```

This has created a graph in a new window with a suitable plot. I am now looking to create an entirely different plot which will pop up in a seperate window for another set of data. I have tried writing this code:

```
newfig = matplotlib.pyplot.loglog(e,f, basex = 2, label = "Timsort")
```

However when I try this, it just adds another label onto the previous graph. Can anyone help me figure out how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what "matplotlib.pyplot.show()" is for.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.random.rand(100,1)
    b = np.random.rand(100,1)
    e = np.random.rand(100,1)
    f = np.random.rand(100,1)


    plt.loglog(a,b, basex = 2, label = 'mergesort')
    plt.ylabel('Time Taken')
    plt.title('Time vs 2^i')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    plt.loglog(e,f, basex = 2, label = "Timsort")
    plt.show()
```

This will generate 2 separate figures/plots

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:
 `fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2)`
and when plotting you can call them by their index. In this case:

```
ax[0].plot(your_data)
  ax[1].plot(your_data_2)
```

The first argument of plt.subplots specifies the number of rows and second argument specifies the number of columns